# How to add prefix index to MySQL using JPA?

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, kotlin, jpa, prefix

I used JPA to operate the MySQL database in springboot. I tried to add a prefix index to the name column, but failed. I wonder if this can be done with JPA. Here is my code

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user_setting", indexes = [Index(columnList = "name")])
class UserSettingTable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    var id: Int = 0

    @Column(name = "name", length = 256, nullable = false)
    var domain: String = ""
}
```

I tried to create it like this, but it didn't work.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user_setting", indexes = [Index(columnList = "name(50)")])
class UserSettingTable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    var id: Int = 0

    @Column(name = "name", length = 256, nullable = false)
    var domain: String = ""
}
```

Additional information:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.2.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/>
</parent>
```

Comment: That's not possible with JPA/Hibernate. You should consider to use FlyWay or Liquibase to create your schema instead

Comment: @SimonMartinelli Thank you. This is a common feature for me. Do you know why JPA doesn't provide this feature.

Comment: This is not SQL standard and JPA only supports the standard